# Adding a new file extension for Kate syntax highlighting did not work as expected

Tags: kde, settings, syntax-highlighting, kate

I want to get Kate to highlight files ending in `.jinja2` as html.

[As described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137989/how-to-change-default-syntax-highlighting-for-header-file-in-kate), I tried adding `*.jinja2` to the markdown/html mime type using settings, but even after closing/reopening Kate, the addition of `*.jinja2` had no effect.

Changing the file extension to .html resulted in the expected highlighting. I tried playing with the priority setting, but no luck.

[image]

Is there something else I need to do to get Kate to associate a custom file extension with a syntax highlighting mode?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have resolved itself. I now have syntax highlighting for html in .jinja2 files. I have no idea why closing and re-opening once was not sufficient.

Edit. I just opened up one .jinja2 document next to another one. One has highlighting, the other does not. Not sure what is going on, if this is a bug or I am overlooking something.